# Why is cy.log() is not printing any values in the left pane in Cypress?

Tags: javascript-objects, cypress, module.exports

I am new to Cypress. I have a repo at https://github.com/martian86/PractiseJavaScript.git

I have a **math.js** file which has a simple code to calculate sum of 2 numbers and another function to return square of the number. There is another file **strings.js** which returns a string. I am using `module.exports` in one of the files and `exports` in another. I intend to print it using cy.log() in the tests written in **test.js**

The tests pass without without error but cy.log() does not print anything.

Can anyone suggest what is going wrong.

**math.js**

```
module.exports = {
    square: (x) =>{
    return x*x;
    },
        sum: (a,b)=>{
           return a+b;
          }
}
```

**test.js**

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />
const { describe } = require("mocha");



let testFirstName = require("/cypress/support/strings.js");
let {square, sum} = require("/cypress/support/math.js");

describe("Test suite",function(){
    it("Square of the number",function(){
        cy.log(square(90));
        cy.log(sum(25,67));
    });

    it("Display Name",function(){
        cy.log(testFirstName.stringsFirstName)
    })
})
```

**strings.js**

```
let firstName = "John";
let lastName = "Cena"

exports.stringsFirstName=firstName;
```

Comment: Can you please add a minimum code where the issue can be reproduced? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Krishna, The test.js file is where the issue lies. Cypress does not log the output of the below lines to the left panel.


cy.log(square(90));

cy.log(sum(25,67));

cy.log(testFirstName.stringsFirstName)




I believe it should calculate the values accordingly and display it on the left panel. My entire code is present in the github link as posted above in the question. Also, the js files are copied in the description as it is in the repo.

Comment: the above code works absolutely fine for me. I am getting values printed in the test runner. Please note that `cy.log()` does not print anything on the terminal. You can expand the passing tests from the test runner to observe the logs.

Comment: Thanks Krishna. I did not know about that. I can see the logs now.

Comment: If anyone wishes to print messages in the terminal, this could come in handy: ```cy.task('log', 'Your message here.');```